# Magento - shopping cart price rule condition is applying on all cart

Tags: magento, action, shopping-cart, conditional-statements, discount

I am using Magento 1.7. The issue is

I have created a rule using these conditions and that works

If ALL of these conditions are TRUE :

If an item is FOUND in the cart with ALL of these conditions true:
Bag Size is 11.5
Brand is XYZ

But when I only want to apply it to the above products and not the whole cart with the same actions

Apply the rule only to cart items matching the following conditions (leave blank for all items)
If ALL of these conditions are TRUE :

Bag Size is 11.5
Brand is XYZ

It doesnt work.  No discount is applied when using the actions tab - apply rule.

Please help.

Please see the screenshots below

[image]

[image]

Comment: I suggest You to post some screenshots of your conditions and actions, in order to be clear

Comment: Please check the screen shots

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to target specific products in the cart, remove all the rules from your **Conditions** tab and only have the **Actions** rules set.

The general rule is:

**Conditions:** - Checks to see if the conditions pass for the entire cart, then allows the rule to be applied to the cart.

**Actions:** - Checks to see if conditionals for the individual items pass, then apply to those individual items.

In your case, you're attempting to target specific items in the cart, so the Condition rules are not needed.

Comment: If I remove conditions and only apply the "action" then it is just saying "Coupon code "xyz" is not valid." however, this coupons is working if use condition. But condition is applying on entire cart.But action is not working. If I just use the attribute "Brand" then it works but when I use the attribute "Bag Size" then it doesnt work on "action"